# GPIO2 not detecting interrupt [python on Board B rev 2]

Tags: raspbian, gpio

I have hooked up pin 26 (GPIO 7) and pin 3 (GPIO 2) with a button between the two, how do I get an interupt (GPIO.add_event_detect) to work on GPIO 2?

I have made this work between other GPIO pins, but not GPIO 2. I've read that it might not be possible since GPIO 2 has a built in pull-up resistor, but I'm hoping someone can help me with a workound.

I need to use GPIO 2 because I'm hooking a dartboard up to it, which requires a minimum of 16 inputs for the matrix -- I am forced to use one or both of the I2C pins.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Pin 3 (GPIO 2) has a 1k8 pull-up resistor, as you mention.

It is not clear how you have wired the circuit. You state you have "a button between the two". Unless you have programmed pin 26 (GPIO 7) as a output and set it low, I would expect this to have no effect on the voltage on pin 3.